# How to keep checkbox checked after switching screens in React

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-hooks, expo, react-navigation

I want to keep the checkboxes checked after switching screens and coming back. Does anyone know how I would do this? The initial state is false for all of them, but is there a way to keep it changed after navigating to a different screen? Here is my code:

```
import { KeyboardAvoidingView, Image, ScrollView, StyleSheet, Switch, Text, View, FlatList, TouchableOpacity, Button, Dimensions, Platform, TextInput } from 'react-native';
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import Checkbox from '../checkbox/Checkbox';

const Edit= props => {
        const [Sun, setSun] = React.useState(false);
        const [Mon, setMon] = React.useState(false);
        const [Tue, setTue] = React.useState(false);
        const [Wed, setWed] = React.useState(false);
        const [Thu, setThu] = React.useState(false);
        const [Fri, setFri] = React.useState(false);
        const [Sat, setSat] = React.useState(false);
    return (
        <View style={styles.EditBackground}>
            <Text style={styles.EditTitle}>Math-255</Text>

            <Text style={styles.InfoText}>Event Name and Instructor:</Text>

            <KeyboardAvoidingView
                behavior={Platform.OS === "ios" ? "padding" : "height"}
                style={styles.writeTaskWrapper}
            >
                <TextInput style={styles.input} placeholder={'Event Name'} />
            </KeyboardAvoidingView>

            <KeyboardAvoidingView
                behavior={Platform.OS === "ios" ? "padding" : "height"}
                style={styles.writeTaskWrapper}
            >
                <TextInput style={styles.input} placeholder={'Instructor (optional)'} />
            </KeyboardAvoidingView>

            <Text style={styles.InfoText}>Location:</Text>

            <KeyboardAvoidingView
                behavior={Platform.OS === "ios" ? "padding" : "height"}
                style={styles.writeTaskWrapper}
            >
                <TextInput style={styles.input} placeholder={'Location (optional)'} />
            </KeyboardAvoidingView>

            <Checkbox
                style={styles.Checkbox}
                title="S"
                onPress={() => setSun(!Sun)}
                isChecked={Sun}
            />
            <Checkbox
                style={styles.Checkbox}
                title="M"
                onPress={() => setMon(!Mon)}
                isChecked={Mon}
              />
              <Checkbox
                style={styles.Checkbox}
                title="T"
                onPress={() => setTue(!Tue)}
                isChecked={Tue}
                
              />
              <Checkbox
                style={styles.Checkbox}
                title="W"
                onPress={() => setWed(!Wed)}
                isChecked={Wed}
              />
              <Checkbox
                style={styles.Checkbox}
                title="TH"
                onPress={() => setThu(!Thu)}
                isChecked={Thu}
              />
              <Checkbox
                style={styles.Checkbox}
                title="F"
                onPress={() => setFri(!Fri)}
                isChecked={Fri}
              />
              <Checkbox
                style={styles.Checkbox}
                title="S"
                onPress={() => setSat(!Sat)}
                isChecked={Sat}
              />

        </View>
        );
    }

    export default Edit;
```

I've tried looking it up and trying some different things but haven't gotten it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Store their state in the [`Context`](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html).

Comment: Can you explain a little bit on how to do this?

Comment: There is nothing to explain, you create a context, in which you store the states from your code above, and pass all their values and functions to the context, which then get available for any descendant component with `useContext()`. As for the actual usage you'll have to read the docs for that. The alternative is to create the states at the `App` component level and then pass all of these functions and value through all props down the rendering tree until you arrive to the component with input. A.K.A prop drilling.